# How to efficiently parse a large XML file in Python?

Tags: python

I have a large XML file containing structured data, and I need to parse it efficiently using Python. However, due to its size, I'm concerned about memory usage and performance. What are some efficient methods or libraries I can use to parse this XML file without consuming excessive memory or slowing down the process? Additionally, are there any optimizations or best practices I should follow while implementing the parsing logic? Any code examples or resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I am expecting a code solving my above issue!

Comment: You should do some research. Many similar questions have already been asked. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+[xml]+parsing+large+file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways I know you can follow are -

Iterative Parsing with ElementTree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def process_element(element):
    # Process each XML element here
    pass

# Iterate over XML elements
for event, element in ET.iterparse('large_file.xml'):
    process_element(element)
    element.clear()
```

Streaming XML Parsing with lxml

```
from lxml import etree

def process_element(element):
    # Process each XML element here
    pass

# Iterate over XML elements
for event, element in etree.iterparse('large_file.xml', events=('start', 'end')):
    if event == 'end':
        process_element(element)
        element.clear()
```